# How to mock object attributes and complex fields and methods?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking

I have a following function which needs to be unit tested.

```
def read_all_fields(all_fields_sheet):
    entries = []

    for row_index in xrange(2, all_fields_sheet.nrows):
        d = {'size' : all_fields_sheet.cell(row_index,0).value,\
             'type' : all_fields_sheet.cell(row_index,1).value,\
             'hotslide' : all_fields_sheet.cell(row_index,3).value}
        entries.append((all_fields_sheet.cell(row_index,2).value,d))

    return entries
```

Now, my all_fields_sheet is a sheet returned by xlrd module(Used to read Excel file).

So, basically I need to mock for following attributes
nrows
cell

How should I go abput it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just mock the calls and attributes directly on a mock object; adjust to cover your test needs:

```
mock_sheet = MagicMock()
mock_sheet.nrows = 3  # loop once
cells = [
    MagicMock(value=42),     # row_index, 0
    MagicMock(value='foo'),  # row_index, 1
    MagicMock(value='bar'),  # row_index, 3
    MagicMock(value='spam'), # row_index, 2
]
mock_sheet.cell.side_effect = cells
```

By assigning a list to [`Mock.side_effect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) you can control, in order, what calls to `.cell()` return.

Afterwards, you can test if the right calls have been made with the various assertion methods. You could use the [`mock.call()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.call) to give precise expectations:

```
result = read_all_fields(mock_sheet)
self.assertEqual(
    result, 
    [('spam', {'size': 42, 'type': 'foo', 'hotslide': 'bar'})]
)

self.assertEqual(
    mock_sheet.cell.call_args_list,
    [call(2, 0), call(2, 1), call(2, 3), call(2, 2)])
```

I used [`Mock.call_args_list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_args_list) here to match an exact number of calls, directly to `mock_sheet.cell` alone.

Demo, assuming that your `read_all_fields()` function is already defined:

```
>>> from unittest.mock import MagicMock, call
>>> mock_sheet = MagicMock()
>>> mock_sheet.nrows = 3  # loop once
>>> cells = [
...     MagicMock(value=42),     # row_index, 0
...     MagicMock(value='foo'),  # row_index, 1
...     MagicMock(value='bar'),  # row_index, 3
...     MagicMock(value='spam'), # row_index, 2
... ]
>>> mock_sheet.cell.side_effect = cells
>>> result = read_all_fields(mock_sheet)
>>> result == [('spam', {'size': 42, 'type': 'foo', 'hotslide': 'bar'})]
True
>>> mock_sheet.cell.call_args_list == [call(2, 0), call(2, 1), call(2, 3), call(2, 2)]
True
```

Alternatively, you could create a function for the `mock_sheet.cell.side_effect` attribute, to return values from a 'sheet' you set up up front:

```
cells = [[42, 'foo', 'spam', 'bar']]  # 1 row
def mock_cells(row, cell):
    return MagicMock(value=cells[row - 2][cell])
mock_sheet.cell.side_effect = mock_cells
```

When `side_effect` is a function, it is called whenever `mock_sheet.cell()` is called, with the same arguments.